# Confusion related to Gale and Shapley algorithm for perfect matching

Tags: algorithms

I have this confusion related to Gale and Shapley algorithm

Claim. GS finds woman-pessimal stable matching S*.

Proof

Suppose A-Z matched in S*, but Z is not worst valid partner for A.
 There exists stable matching S in which A is paired with a man, say
Y, whom she likes less than Z.
 Let B be Z's partner in S.
 Z prefers A to B.
 Thus, A-Z is an unstable in S.

Now, I find it really strange how it is proved here. I didn't get what they are trying to do here and how they are proving the claim. Can anyone provide some insights?

Answer (score 2):

This is a proof by contradiction. It assumes that there is a stable matching $S$ in which $A$ has a worse partner than in the stable matching $S^*$ produced by the Gale–Shapley algorithm, and derives a contradiction.

"$Z$ is not the worst valid partner for $A$": That such a pair exists follows from the assumption that $S^*$ is not "woman-pessimal" (never heard that term before :-). Here $A$ is a woman and $Z$ is a man.

The next sentence just explicates this: a "valid" partner of a woman here is one that can be her partner in a stable matching, so if $Z$ is not $A$'s worst valid partner, there is a stable matching $S$ in which $A$ is paired with a worse partner, say $Y$.

"$Z$ prefers $A$ to $B$": This is the clue. This follows from the man-optimality of $S^*$. (If you haven't proved this yet, you can find a proof of it in [these slides](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/lectures/intro-marriage-4up.pdf), on the slide titled "Proof of Fact $3$".) Since $Z$ is married to $A$ in $S^*$, $S^*$ is man-optimal among all stable matchings, and both $S$ and $S^*$ are stable, $Z$ prefers $A$ to $B$.

"Thus, $A$-$Z$ is unstable in $S$.": This now follows because $Z$ prefers $A$ to $B$ and $A$ prefers $Z$ to $Y$.